# zsh run a command stored in a variable?

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh

In a shell script (in .zshrc) I am trying to execute a command that is stored as a string in another variable.  Various sources on the web say this is possible, but I'm not getting the behavior i expect. Maybe it's the `~` at the beginning of the command, or maybe it's the use of `sudo`, I'm not sure.  Any ideas?  Thanks

```
function update_install()
{
    # builds up a command as a string...
    local install_cmd="$(make_install_command $@)"
    # At this point the command as a string looks like: "sudo ~some_server/bin/do_install arg1 arg2"
    print "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    print "Will update install"
    print "With command: ${install_cmd}"
    print "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    echo "trying backticks"
    `${install_cmd}`
    echo "Trying \$()"
    $(${install_cmd})
    echo "Trying \$="
    $=install_cmd
}
```

Output:

```
Will update install
With command: sudo ~some_server/bin/do_install arg1 arg2

trying backticks
update_install:9: no such file or directory: sudo ~some_server/bin/do_install arg1 arg2
Trying $()
update_install:11: no such file or directory: sudo ~some_server/bin/do_install arg1 arg2
Trying $=
sudo ~some_server/bin/do_install arg1 arg2: command not found
```

Comment: you could use `zsh -c '${install_cmd}'`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `eval`:

```
eval ${install_cmd}
```

Comment: Nice, simple approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

As explained in [§3.1 "Why does `$var` where `var="foo bar"` not do what I expect?" of the Z-Shell FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html), you can use the `shwordsplit` shell option to tell `zsh` that you want it to split variables up by spaces and treat them as multiple words. That same page also discusses alternatives that you might want to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers are correct, what worked for me was the below command in zsh

```
totalin=$(eval echo testing |wc -l)
echo "Total: $totalin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two problems here - the first is that your `install_cmd` is being interpreted as a single string, instead of a command (`sudo`) with 3 arguments.

Your final attempt `$=install_cmd` actually does solve that problem correctly (though I'd write it as `${=install_cmd}` instead), but then you hit your second problem: `~some_server/bin/do_install` is not a known command.  This is because `sudo` doesn't interpret the `~` like you intend, for safety reasons; it would need to evaluate its arguments using the shell (or do some special-casing for `~`, which is really none of `sudo`'s business), which opens up a whole can of worms that, understandably, `sudo` does its best to avoid.

That's also why it worked to do `eval ${install_cmd}` - because that's literally treating the whole string as a thing to be evaluated, possibly containing multiple commands (e.g. if `install_cmd` contained `echo foo; sudo rm -rf /` it would be happy to wipe your system).

You have to be the one to decide whether you want `install_cmd` to allow full shell semantics, including variable interpolation, path expansion, multiple commands, etc. or whether it should just expand the words out and run them as a single command.