# Assigning command to a variable in Zsh

Tags: zsh

I recently switched over to Zsh, and I have some configuration shell files I want to load into Zsh.  However, it doesn't appear Zsh allows for command assignment by string to a variable.

### What used to work

```sh
local git_conf='git config --global'
$git_conf rebase.autosquash true
```

In Bash the above works fine.  However in Zsh it prints out:

```
command not found: git config --global
```

If I simply write the whole command out in the same file it works, but if I assign a partial command to a variable it doesn't.  Is there a way around this?

Thanks,

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665172/zsh-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable

Comment: @zedfoxus - that absolutely does.  I just found that too.  I asked a little early, the google wasn't giving me the best results when I first ran into this issue.  What's neat is that in Zsh I can loop through an array of strings to assign these configurations.  Thank yoU!

Comment: Now if it works with assigning git functions: `git config --global alias.coo '!f() { ... }'` that would be amazing.

Comment: Great going. I'm sure you'll find a way to make your workflow amazing :)

Comment: @zedfoxus - absolutely, I'll update this with an answer for others in case they run into mine first before the other.  Hope your workflow is amazing! :)

Comment: Don't use the bash tag for zsh questions. (A good place to start: Is bash expertise necessary and sufficient to make it answerable?)

Comment: By the way, the best practice is never to use variables to store commands even in bash -- use functions instead, as described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). The function equivalent to your sample would be `git_conf() { git config --global "$@"; }`, after which one can run `git_conf rebase.autosquash true` on _any_ POSIX-compliant shell (and some noncompliant ones like zsh).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy "Eval is evil" is true, but not sure about that in bash context.  Nontheless I like the best practice approach.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.  Thank you.

Comment: With respect to eval-is-evil-in-bash, see [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). It certainly _is_ possible to use safely, but takes some care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has already been answered.  I asked a little early before my due diligence with the google.  So I'll put in my answer below.

### Solution

Using the `eval` function will work.  But this is not best practice.  For best practice I'm using a shell function.

In my case I have a lot of duplicate configurations that shorthands some of the typing so it's not as verbose.  In this case I've further opted for an associative array of configurations considering each configuration will have a unique key.

```sh
declare -A confs
confs=(
    rebase.autosquash true
    alias.a '!ga() {
        if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
            git add .
        else
            git add "$@"
        fi
    }; ga'
)

for key value in ${(kv)confs}
do
  # this works, however I'd like to stay away from eval whenever possible
  # command="specific command that's always the same ${key} ${value}"
  # eval ${command}

  # best practice
  git_config ${key} ${value}
done

git_config() {
    git config --global "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your want the shell to split your "command" on the spaces. Hence you have to invoke it as

```
${(z)git_conf} rebase.autosquash true
```

Of course this is a misuse of shell variables and works in such simple cases. I wonder why you do want to use a shell variable here, and not - say - a shell function. Even using an array variable would be more flexible.

Comment: In the comments section it was told to me that it is best practice to use a shell function.  I have changed my answer to reflect best practice.

Comment: Well, don't use a truck, if you can also transport your wine using a bicycle. Of course using parameter expansion to expand to a full command (including parameters) is something we try to avoid, but your original question is valid, since there are cases where indeed a function can't bring you further. Actually, if you go so far that you are using a function instead, you could also make it even more flexible if you can turn it into a separated script. A function can only be executed from within the zsh process which defines it, while a script can be run from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
local git_conf=(git config --global)
"$git_conf[@]" rebase.autosquash true
```